# ADB2C Custom Attribute String Data Size

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

What is the max size (number of characters) that a String Custom Attribute can hold on Active Directory B2C?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maximum length for a **String** property is 256 characters.

For more information, see [Directory schema extensions | Graph API concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions).